# Flutter LinearLayout weight alternative

Tags: layout, flutter

I'm Android developer learning flutter. I want my screen looks like this:

```
|---------------------------------|
|                                 |
|  Babe               I miss you  |
|                                 |
|---------------------------------|
```

"Babe" and "I miss you" should be two separate elements.

With Android xml I would solve this with `LinearLayout` and two `TextView`s with `weight=1` for each. What's the alternative for flutter?

P.S. I know that you can solve it with `FrameLayout` or with `RelativeLayout` but I want closest to `LinearLayout` behavior.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Flutter's [`Row`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) widget is equivalent to android's `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="horizontal"`,
and [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) widget is equivalent to android's `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`.

[`flex`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html) property of [`Flexible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html) widget is equivalent `weight` property, you can wrap the `Text` widgets in a `Flexible` widget and specify the `flex` property.

Example:

```
new Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Flexible(child: new Text("Babe"), flex: 1,),
      new Flexible(child: new Text("I miss you"), flex: 1,)
    ],
  )
```

Comment: Each elements is on new line :(

Comment: Flex is what I was looking for. Thanks man. Now I can display two listviews alongside.

Comment: Along with ````flex:1```` i also added ````fit: FlexFit.tight```` to fulfill my need.

Answer (score 38):

Using an [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget can also produce a LinearLayout effect like so:

```
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(child: Text("Babe")),
      flex: 2,
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(child: Text("I don't miss you"),alignment: Alignment.centerRight),
      flex: 2,
    ),
   ],
  ),
```

Comment: This behaves exactly as the weights of LinearLayout. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 10):

Considering the layout in the question you want to display both the texts at the end of screen one at the beginning other at the end you can simply add `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` property to the row

so you need to modify your code to

```
child: new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
     new Text('Babe'),
     new Text('I miss you')
     ]
  )
```

[image: ![enter image description here]
I dont understand why first answer was accepted because it simply adds both the text to right most end of the screen,

**Tip: Incase you need some padding around each text wrap each of the text in a Container and add desired padding and margin**

Answer (score 8):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Use `Spacer` which comes with a `flex` property (defaults to `1`)

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('Hello'),
    Spacer(), // <-- Use this
    Text('World'),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This is the right answer. In the approved solution the widgets are not separated, they only have different sizes and alignment for the texts.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`row`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Row-class.html) with [`MainAxisAlignment`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html) which will allow you to place elements as per your expectation

```
Widget textSection = new Container(
  child: new Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
     new Text('Babe'),
     new Text('I miss you')
  )
)
```

Comment: Have to use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` to get desirable UI. Thank you

Comment: I dont know why this answer was accepted it doesn't produce the desired result.instead use MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

Answer (score 1):

```
       new Container(
          child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

          children: <Widget> [
          new Text('Babe', style: AppStyle.AppBarTextStyle,),
          new Text('I miss you',style: AppStyle.AppBarTextStyle,)
          ]
          )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [FractionallySizedBox](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) widget to give weight sum for both width and height.

```
 FractionallySizedBox(
  heightFactor: .5,
  widthFactor: 1.0,
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: child,
)
```

For more info:

[Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEsY654EGZ0)